# Qt4 Designer widgets error

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I used Qt4Designer to design an application UI.
I did this but when I was converting it to a `.py` file via pyuic4 as below:

```
pyuic4 myui.ui > myui.py
```

I facet to an error that said: `Error: Q3Support widgets are not supported by PyQt4.`

what is this error's reason?

Can we use all widgets placed in designer? for example `KDatePicker`, `Q3Table` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Q3Support` classes are only there to help with porting a **Qt3** application to Qt4. There's absolutely *no reason* to use them in new code. And in any case, they will be dropped completely for Qt5 (which is not far away now).

There's nothing much to add regarding the error message you got, as it could hardly be clearer. The `Q3Support` widgets are not supported by PyQt4. Which is to say, PyQt4 simply does not wrap any of those particular Qt classes.

As for the KDE widgets: they are not directly supported by PyQt either.

To use them with python, you would require [PyKDE4](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python) - and the ui files would need to be compiled with [pykdeuic4](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.3-api/designer.html).

Comment: but another thing that remains here is that QtDesigner version 4.8.1 witch uses Qt version 4.8.1. So the designer's widget that I said in the question such as `KDatePicker`, `Q3Table` have to work correctly. now how can I use this widget in QtDesigner and convert it to pyqt?

Comment: @Amin. I think my answer explains the situation quite clearly - so I have nothing further to add.

Comment: The error's reason was my first question but at the end I asked how can we use from this widget. Rely I faced to an confusing unusual thing. I created my form with QtDesigner witch is contain some widgets and it's preview is showing form correctly but when I want to convert my `.ui` file into `.py` facing to error. we now face to these question. if can we use these widget so how? but if can not to use why they are in designer.

Comment: @Amin. Designer is part of Qt, which is a **C++** library. If you wrote your Qt application in C++, you could use all the widgets. PyQt/PyKDE allow you to write your Qt/KDE application in Python, and they provide the `pyuic` and `pykdeuic` tools to convert Designer `ui` files into Python modules - but not every Qt/KDE class is supported. That's just the way it is at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Is there any prepared widget collection for PyQt?

Comment: sorry @ekhumoro. I wanted to accept the answer at the end of discussion!!

Comment: @Amin. To answer your other question: it's only the **KDE** and **Qt3 Support** widgets you *can't* use with PyQt. All the others are okay (including Phonon). If in doubt, try to compile the ui file with `pyuic` - it will show errors if you use the wrong widgets.

Comment: You are right and I was wrong. thanks for attention. really I saw some extention for example `Extjs` [link]http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/  and so on in another programming language that help us with many prepared tools for example grids, forms, charts and etc. I took a look to the QtDesigner and thought that it can help us with prepared widgets but now faced to this condition. I believe it is necessary for a designing language to have prepared tools. so what is your opinion?